# PhpStorm - Getting a file's modification time

Tags: macos, metadata, phpstorm

Can I view a file's last modification date and time from within the project file browser in PhpStorm?

I'm using Mac OS X and am hoping there's an easier method than right clicking the file and selecting Reveal in Finder. Is there something analogous to Get Info?

Screen shot attached shows no "Get Info" or "Properties" or otherwise helpful option.

[image]

Comment: There is no such action or option.

Comment: @LazyOne Okay, I figured that might be the case, but it seems getting metadata on a file, such as last mod date or permissions or whatever, would be an obvious feature to include in an IDE. I want to be sure I'm not missing something obvious!

Comment: Yes, it seems that IDE keeps such info (used when checking if file was modified outside of IDE and if it needs re-indexing) .. but it's not displayed anywhere (they way you wanted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in current IDE versions (2016.2 and 2016.3).

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107821
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125956
- other tickets linked in those two
- check whole Issue Tracker for other/better tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: P.S. If you wish (have time and know Java/Kotlin) -- you may try writing a plugin that can display such info: 1) [Plugin Development Docs](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html) 2) [API Forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it's very helpful. Being new to JB's tools I wasn't aware of their public issue tracker.